# How can I identify external keyboard being accessing the UITextfields

Tags: ios, keyboard, hide, show

In my iOS application I am using accessory view as well I am shifting the view when keyboard is launching. But when i am using external keyboard (Bluetooth device) i do not need to show accessory view as well view shifting I need to avoid for that use case.
Is there any delegate which can identify the precedence i.e either virtual keyboard will be launched or external keyboard is activated.

Thanks in advance

Kirti

Comment: Have you checked using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification ? Is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

When keyboard will appear **keyboardWillShow** will be broadcasted on using **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
 object:nil];
```

If you are using any bluetooth keyboard then this notification will not be broadcasted.So if you use this to adjust views for the software keyboard, you should handle that based on this notification.

Otherwise you can check the keyboard size differences in the userInfo property of the notification.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It's posted on tap on `UITextView`.

Comment: @Altaveron read the question carefully before commenting/downvoting any answer.